# Should I use past tense of the verb in the following sentence?

Tags: tense

I thought my personality would change when I **reached/ reach** the age of twenty.

Answer (score -2):

You should say:

> I thought my personality would **have changed** when I **had reached** the age of twenty.

Which is [3rd conditional](http://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/grammar/if.htm), and that because using *thought* you imply a *past* event, which cannot be changed.

---

Let's say you are under the age of twenty, then you should say:

> I *think* my personality will change when I reach the age of twenty

which is the 1st conditional.

---

Your expression is the 2nd conditional, let's say you are under the age of twenty, and believe you will die before your birthday:

> I *think* my personality would **change**, if I **reached** the age of twenty